# VS2010 and Windows XP SP3

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

At home I've been running VS 2010 on a Windows 7 x64 machine without any issues, however at work we recently switched over to VS 2010 running on WinXP SP3 x86 - and I gotta say, the experience is terrible.

There are severe graphical glitches. For ex,

1. Intellisense doesn't quite work. You can start typing and the intellisense dropdown window seems to be working, but the text I'm typing vanishes. I can't see it until I hit the Escape key or refresh the window by say, alt-tabbing to another application and then back again to VS2010
2. If I cut/copy/paste and then move the cursor around by scrolling or using the arrow keys, different parts of the text window don't update themselves properly. I can see patches of a different piece of code where it shouldn't be.

Other team members are also facing the similar issues as well. Is there some patch that I should install? I have already installed the UIA 3 patch ScottGu mentioned in his blog.

Any help would be appreciated.

-Thanks!

Comment: Is "dump XP" a valid solution?

Comment: Yes, codeka, the solution to visual glitches in the IDE is to spend thousands of dollars to replace the OS for all the developers.

Comment: What's the end of support date for XP?

Comment: @Gabe: You'd gain a lot of productivity moving dev boxes up to Win7 x64

Comment: I'd love to upgrade to Win7 x64, but sadly I don't have that kind of authority at work. At home however, I'm running a decent dev box - Core i7 930, 6 GB RAM, Nvidia Geforce 8800 GT, Dual HDDs :-D

Comment: I have used VStudio 2010 on WinXP SP3 without any problems ,and with good performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I finally found the solution eventually. The trick is to turn off hardware rendering completely through the registry. Here's the link- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970912.aspx#disablehardwareacceleration

Answer (score 4):

Try disabling hardware rendering (if it is enabled):

Uncheck `Tools->Options->Environment->General->Enable rich client visual experience`.  You may also need to uncheck `Tools->Options->Environment->General->Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance`.

Comment: That's the only real thing I could think of.  We've seen various issues like that, but they almost always end up being graphics card/driver problems, usually solved by turning off rich client graphics.  You should probably file a bug on [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at the [system requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/ultimate) for 2010.

Yes, XP with SP3 is supported, but is the video card in your desktop DirectX 9 capable?  Also, does it have enough video RAM?  I'm guessing if you are using a system that is still running XP, that it is an older machine... which generally means the video is crap.

You might just have to upgrade that.  As a side note if you are using a machine where the video is built in to the motherboard, then you **really** want to go buy a real video card.

If the card is DX9, is not built in to the  motherboard, and has a decent amount of RAM available, then you might look at the video drivers to see if there are new ones available.

Note, when VS 2005 first shipped, we had the same visual glitches and a very slow design surface.  In some cases the design surface wouldn't even bother showing.  After dropping in a decent video card (at the time), visual studio rocked.  I expect 2010 with all its eye candy has exactly the same issues.

Comment: The system requirements check out. The work machine is a C2D with 2 GB ram. The graphics card is an onboard integrated Intel one. It confirms to WPF tier 1 standards with a decent amount of (shared) video ram.

Could this be more of a WPF issue than a VS 2010 one? I don't have much experience running WPF apps on XP. Could anyone comment?

Comment: I would expect problems with that machine configuration.  Do yourself a favor, go buy one decent video card, plop it into one of the machines.  Get the latest video drivers, then run VS2010.  You'll see exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel / System / Advanced / Performance and select "Adjust for best appearance". It took care of that problem on my machine.